# Error: `stat_count()` requires an x or y aesthetic

Tags: r

I'm working on a project where I pass the name of a csv and pdf file into the command line, and save a frequency bar graph to a pdf file. When I run the code in Rstudio it works just fine, but when I run it on the command line I get an error saying that: `stat_count()` requires an x or y aesthetic. What is causing this error? I have included my code below:

```r
generation_freq <-
  data |>
  dplyr::filter(score != 0) |>
  as.data.frame()

ggGeneration <- ggplot(data = generation_freq,
       mapping = aes(x = generation)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count",
           color = "black",
           fill = "skyblue") +
  labs(x = "Generation",
       y = "Number of Correct Guesses",
       title = "Number of Correct Guesses vs Generation of the Pokemon") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Generation", labels = as.character(generation_freq$generation),
                     breaks = generation_freq$generation)

ggsave(filename = generationsPlot,plot = ggGeneration)
```

`data` is the name of the data frame sourced from the CSV file, and `generationsPlot` is the name of the PDF file the plot will be written to.

I looked online for similar errors but people only seemed to run into this kind of error when they wanted to plot something other than count on the y-axis, and forgot to specify that in `geom_bar()`.

generation_freq sample:

```
structure(list(mystery.pokemon = c("Charmander", "Gligar", "Mantine", 
"Slowking", "Wurmple", "Makuhita", "Overqwil", "Toucannon", "Exeggutor", 
"Victini", "Corvisquire", "Espurr", "Gigalith", "Toxel", "Litleo", 
"Vibrava", "Furfrou"), generation = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
8L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 6L), hints = c(2L, 7L, 
3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 7L), 
    guesses = c(1L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), score = c(8L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(generation_freq)`.

Comment: Also, don't use `$` inside of `aes()` _e.g._ `aes(x = generation)`, not `aes(x = generation_freq$generation)`.

Comment: Edited my original post to include the small representative dataset. I also implemented the fix to aes() you suggested

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Running your code I get a warning that "Use of `generation_freq$generation` is discouraged. Use `generation` instead", but everything else works (I do get a plot).  Have you tried this from a clean R session, with just your shortened example?

Comment: I cannot reproduce either - it runs from the RStudio console without issues. What do you mean by "run it on the command line" ?

Comment: Are you possibly forgetting to load the `dplyr` package (or the whole `tidyverse` meta-package?) That could lead to calling the wrong version of `filter` and messing things up in interesting ways ...

Comment: You were right, Ben! I forgot to load dplyr package, and after doing that it works!

I do get this message, however:

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Saving 7 x 7 in image

Is this a problem?